# Unsatisfied link error Library not found

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I want to extract Text from image simply implement OCR(Optical Character Recognition) in Android using Library LEPTONICA and TESSERACT.I have succesfully added the open source library to my sample project But when i am running my application but on run time app force closes and error was .... ExceptioninInitialization UnspecifiedLink Error...Library Not found

Any suggetion how to resolve this error...I am stuck on this

Comment: make sure you have added the library to the same location where your workspace exist...

Comment: yes I have added it to same location...

Comment: What is the Android API version of your Emulator or Device? And your android ndk version?

Comment: I am using android version 8...actually i am beginner in NDK so i dont know about it..i just use the open source library (LEPTONICA) in my project...please Guide me for same its very Urgent for me..

Comment: Did you successfully compile the library? check `lib\armeabi` folder for `*.so`.

Comment: I didnt compile the Library...please help how to compile it...thnx

Comment: First get some knowledge about NDK. Here is the getting started guide [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html). First try to compile the `hello-jni` program from your ndk samples. `<ANDROID_NDK>/samples/hello-jni`. Check the above link to know how to compile `hello-jni`.

Comment: Did you find the solutiin fir that...@dipankar .. If yes tyen please share